# Proving statements vs disproving statements

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

This exercise came from my discrete mathematics book.

> Determine which statements are true and which are false. Prove those that are true and disprove those that are false.
>
> > problem 6:  $\frac{\sqrt 2}{6}$
> > is rational.

I assumed that $\frac{\sqrt 2}{6}$ being rational was true.

- My first attempt was to use prove by contradiction. So, i assumed that $√2/6$ is irrational, which led to a dead-end since you can't proof irrationality.
- My second attempt was a direct proof:

> Proof:
> Suppose $\frac{\sqrt 2}{6}$ is rational. By definition of rational, there exists integers $p$ and $q$ such $\frac{\sqrt 2}{6}=\frac{q}{p}$   with $q≠0$.
> Then, $\frac{\sqrt 2}{6}=\frac{q}{p}$$⟹$ $\sqrt{2}=\frac{q}{p}*6$ $⟹$ $\sqrt{2}=\frac{6q}{p}$
> Note that $6p$ and $q$ are integers since $p$ and $q$ are integers. Also, $q≠0$ by the zero-product property. Hence, by definition of rational, there exists integers $6p$ and $q$ such that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{6q}{p}$; thus, $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. However, there is a contradiction since we know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

From here I discovered that the statement I am trying to prove is false.

- So, I figured that I should disprove the statement.

At the time the only method of disprove I know was counterexample. So, I tried to come up with a counterexample, but the problem is not knowing how to provide a counterexample while dealing with square root.

---

I searched online for other ways to disprove statements that didn't require a counterexample.

I came across this pdf:
["How to disprove statements"](https://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof2/Disproof.pdf)

In this they introduce the concept of disproof:

> It turns out that there is a very simple and
> utterly convincing procedure that proves a statement is false. The process
> of carrying out this procedure is called disproof.
>
> > Suppose you want to
> > disprove a statement $P$. In other words you want to prove that $P$ is false.
> > The way to do this is to prove that $∼ P$ is true, for if $∼ P$ is true, it follows
> > immediately that $P$ has to be false

They then separate them into universal disproof, which is just counterexample.

> To disprove a universally quantified statement such as $∀x ∈ S,P(x)$
>
> > we must prove its negation. Its negation is
> > $∼ (∀x ∈ S,P(x)) = ∃ x ∈ S,∼P(x)$.
> > The negation is an existence statement. To prove the negation is true,
> > we just need to produce an example of an x ∈ S that makes ∼ P(x) true.

Now Disproof by Contradiction is the part I am interested in:

> Contradiction can be a very useful way to disprove a statement. To see
> how this works, suppose we wish to disprove a statement P. We know
> that to disprove $P$, we must prove $∼ P$. To prove $∼ P$ with contradiction,
> we assume $∼∼ P$ is true and deduce a contradiction. But since $∼∼ P = P$,
> this boils down to assuming P is true and deducing a contradiction.

---

So, my question is whether Disproof by Contradiction is valid method, or if there are better ways of disproving mathematical statements?

Comment: Formatting is a good idea...it's not clear whether you are speaking of $\frac {\sqrt 2}6$ or $\sqrt {\frac 26}$.  Also, assuming rationality and deriving a contradiction is, of course, proof by contradiction.  And the claim that "you can't prove irrationality" is contradicted by your post (as you do, in fact, prove irrationality).

Comment: @lulu: *And the claim that "you can't prove irrationality" is contradicted by your post* -- I was wondering about this myself, and began getting lost after that and so I didn't continue. Maybe the "can't prove irrationality" was an oversight in wording? Regarding this specific problem, I think the big picture a student is supposed to realize from doing this is that multiplying by (or dividing by; or adding to; or subtracting from) a nonzero rational number doesn't change rationality/irrationality status. So if you are allowed to use the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, then $\ldots$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro  And, of course, there are cases in which you can prove irrationality directly.  $\sum 10^{-n!}$ is clearly irrational, say (as there are arbitrarily long blocks of $0's$).  But, yes.  Here, if you are allowed to assume the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ (or $\sqrt 3$ depending on which was meant), there's not much to prove.

Comment: A counterexample is only a valid method for a  disproof , if the claim is of the form "for every ..."

Comment: We need the law of the excluded middle , but virtually every mathematician accepts this law. Without it , many important results cannot be proven.

Comment: There are in fact seemingly easy cases , where irrationality has not yet been established. In general such proofs are extremely difficult , of course not for $\sqrt{2}$. The unsolved cases include $e+\pi$ , $e\cdot \pi$ and $\gamma$ , the Euler-Mascheroni-constant.

Comment: Omar, the answer to the question at the end of your Question is "Yes it is." Are you looking for more than that?

Comment: When I said, "you can't prove irrationality", I meant that a rational number has a straightforward definition compared to irrational numbers. my bad i should have worded it better.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I will try to reword what I said better: My problem is that i know "√2/6 is rational" is false, so how do I show that it's false? normally the statements provide are true but how do i deal with false statements.  i already tried using counterexample but it went nowhere.

Comment: This "Disproof by Contradiction" is completely standard.  (And incidentally, in some systems of formal logic, $\lnot P$ is *defined* to mean exactly the same thing as $P \rightarrow \bot$ where $\bot$ is the false proposition; so this would be a special case of "Conditional Proof" where you prove $P \rightarrow Q$ by assuming $P$ and concluding $Q$.)

Comment: *My problem is that i know "√2/6 is rational" is false, so how do I show that it's false?* --- I think for this problem (and your discrete math course) you're digging too deep into purely formal logic matters. Being a real number, √2/6 is either rational or irrational. So if √2/6 is not rational (what it means to say "√2/6 is rational" is false), then √2/6 must be irrational (What else could it be? Only two possibilities, and one possibility has been eliminated). So you're saying that you know √2/6 is irrational. OK, then prove "√2/6 is irrational" is true, i.e. prove that √2/6 is irrational.